# How to play music by for loop Onelinelistite in kivymd?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Music play with For loop OneLineListItme in kivymd

I'm try to play my music by pressing Onelinelistitem but when I press any list item it's only play one muaic

**main.py**

```
for FILE, PATH in self.MUSIC.items():
            #for folder in self.MUS_DIR:
            LIST_MUSIC = TwoLineListItem(
                    text = FILE + str(ID),
                    secondary_text = PATH,
                    font_style = "Caption"
                    ) ; ID+=1
                    
            LIST_MUSIC.id = str(ID)
            
            FILE_PATH = os.path.join(LIST_MUSIC.secondary_text, LIST_MUSIC.text)
            
            LIST_MUSIC.bind(on_press = lambda x : self.Play_Music(FILE_PATH))
            
            IDS.MUSIC_LIST.add_widget(LIST_MUSIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when using a `lambda` in a loop. The created `lambda` function remembers the name of the variable `FILE_PATH`, not its current value. So whenever that `lambda` method gets executed, it uses the current value of `FILE_PATH`, which is the last value that it was assigned in the loop. The fix is to force the evaluation of `FILE_PATH` by using another variable in the `lambda`, like this:

```
LIST_MUSIC.bind(on_press=lambda x, y=FILE_PATH: self.Play_Music(y))
```